# Fabric.js text missing in SVG export in IE 11+

Tags: svg, html5-canvas, export, internet-explorer-11, fabricjs

As can be seen on the [fabric.js site](http://fabricjs.com/test/svg_export/text.html) itself.
Text in an exported SVG will not show up in the SVG in IE11.

I'm wondering if this is a known issue, or if anyone has faced &/ fixed it :)

I can't find anybody mentioning this as an issue so I thought it must be something I was doing, but I can see that the text export doesn't work even on the fabric site itself. [image: FabricJS Text Export Test In IE11]

Comment: Did you check in prev. versions?

Comment: @Durga No I haven't. Do you know if there is an easy way to pull old versions into a codepen so I can create a pen to test the SVG export with older versions? This issue seem to be present all the way up to newest EDGE so I'd love to fix it!

Comment: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js` change version number in link

Comment: Ah! It works up to 1.7.16 but from then on it is broken!

Comment: V1.7.17 and up are adding 'white-space: pre;' to the style of the text tag. This for some reason is making IE and edge not display the text at all.